# How is $ −0.408792 = \overline{1}.591208?$

Tags: logarithms

$$\log x = −24\times \log(1.04) = (−24) \times 0.017033 = −0.408792
= \overline{1}.591208 = \overline{1} .5912 \text{(approx)}$$
[image: better view in the image]

How did the negative value turn into positive?

Comment: $-0.408792\neq 1.591208$.  Are you sure you didn't crop the image poorly or have some important signs missing?  Further, in the linked image there is an overline on the one, $\overline{1}.591208$... what is that meant to represent here?  It has no defined meaning in this context that I am aware of...

Comment: exactly, I couldn't find the formula they used to make the value with overline.

Comment: If you are tasked with solving $\log(x)=-24\times \log(1.04)$ (*regardless which base is intended for the log, be it $\ln, \log_{10}$ or even $\log_2$*), use the property that $a\log b = \log b^a$ to learn that $\log(x)=-24\times\log(1.04)\implies \log(x)=\log(1.04^{-24})$ which since $\log$ is an injective function on its domain in the reals implies $x=1.04^{-24}\approx 0.39012$

Comment: It seems to be $1.591208=2+(-0.408792)$ though it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen the notation $\bar{1}.5912$ on this site before. From context, I inferred that it meant $-1 + 0.5912$ (which is indeed equal to $-0.4088$). It's written this way because if you have a $\log$ table, you look up $0.5912$ in the table, then multiply your answer by the base to the power of $-1$.

Comment: I confirm this the notation used when computations were mage with logarithm tables (before computers). In $\bar n.xxxxxx$ denoted the integer part of the logarithm when this logarithm is negative.

Comment: Basically its a business administration math and here is the full solution of the math: https://ibb.co/gW65sR

Comment: @Nilot Now that you know what the notation means, can you follow the solution clearly?

Comment: @Y.Forman as I don't understand maths much, can you tell me what will be the value of -0.2574 and how?

Comment: @Nilot What do you mean "what will be the value"? (And I can't see where that number comes up in the solution you posted.)

Comment: @Y.Forman it's from another problem where I stuck. it will be logx = -0.2574

Comment: @Nilot Are you using log tables? If you have a calculator, you don't have to bother with the bar notation -- just type in $10^{-0.408792}$ for your first example or $10^{-0.2574}$ for this new one

Comment: @Y.Forman Got it. So by this I will directly get the value of 'x' and can skip the bar notation & anti log. I got the value of x = 0.5528. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The notation reflects the form $$x=a \times 10^n$$where $1\le a \lt 10$ and $n$ is an integer. Tables are produced in this range for $0\le \log_{10} a \lt 1$ and one writes $\log_{10} x = n+\log_{10} a$ if $n\ge 0$ and $ x=\bar n+\log_{10} a$ concatenating as if a decimal, if $n\lt 0$.  One deals with the integer parts and the fractional parts separately - the fractional parts sometimes give a carry.

This was taught in my school in the 1970s, and facilitated computation based on the use of tables. There were other aids like slide rules (where keeping track of the power of ten was also essential). Now, of course, it is a lot less common.

Comment: [+1] Full agreement : at that time "logarithms" were  considered as a kind of numbers "not as the others", partly due to this bar-notation. Instead of your last sequence, I would have written : "I thought, now that, for at least twenty years, "log" is a button on pocket computers,  this notation had been completely eradicated...